# Could you help me translate these comments about Messi leaving Barcelona?

Tags: translation

There's [this news](https://tieba.baidu.com/p/6927305612?da_from=ZGFfbGluZT1EVCZkYV9wYWdlPTEmZGFfbG9jYXRlPXAwMDY0JmRhX2xvY19wYXJhbT0xJmRhX3Rhc2s9dGJkYSZkYV9vYmpfaWQ9MjY5MzEmZGFfb2JqX2dvb2RfaWQ9NDcwNzAmZGFfdGltZT0xNTk5Mzg0NDA1&da_sign=c628fce3efca1f58a14a2fb55d0f12f2&tieba_from=tieba_da). I'm reading comments, not quite understanding what the authors meant. I hope this kind of grouped questions are OK on Chinese Stack Exchange. I don't want to exaggerate, so I'll only put a handful of them. I'll gladly accept answers which respond only partially to these.

1. *促销巨惠，等你来* - I don't know how to translate this.
2. *这波反转我吐了* - I think it's something like "I've had enough of this storm of ever-changing information"?
3. *影帝 梅西* - 帝 is emperor, but this 影? What's 影帝? Google Translate says it means "Actor", so does the author mean that Messi fakes fouls?
4. *整理了一些（p.s，p.r）存货，都是干货* - I don't know how to translate it.
5. *讲的通俗易懂，都学完了，有想学习的吗？* - shouldn't 的 be 得? I know 通俗易懂 means "easy to understand", but I don't understand this sentence.
6. *再发挥一下价值，分享给有缘人。* - the first part probably means "Once again he's reminding his value", but what's after comma is incomprehensible for me.
7. *需要的留下邮箱，发给你* - I have no idea what it means.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Half of these you could run through Google translate, as you did with number 3, and have some sort of idea what is being said - but you've written *no idea* and *don't know how to translate* - you could show a little more homework than this.

Comment: @Mo I could, I've already tried myself, but it doesn't make sense. It's all guessing. Chinese meanings are very often totally unexpected to me, that's why I didn't want to write anything, because it's very probably that it'd make no sense. For example 4: 整理了 - arranged (who? When?); 一些 - a little;（p.s，p.r）- ???????; 存货 - stock (what stock?)，都是干货 - everything (what everything?) is dry fruit (??????). I hope you understand why I see it as pointless.

Comment: I guess my point is: if you explain specifically why it doesn't make sense to you - it makes it easier for us to give you more helpful answers.

Comment: If your goal is to know Chinese football fans' reaction to Messi's news, the link you gave is not  really a good source. It is not from a popular sub-site and many of the commentators are not even football fans. Some of the comments you quoted in this question are not related to the news at all. I'm from China and often read football news. If you really want to know, here is what I have seen: There are roughly two kinds of reactions among Chinese football fans. Messi's fans understand and support his decision no matter what it is. Those who are not his fans do not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
促销巨惠，等你来 - great discount, waiting for you.
这波反转我吐了 - The dramatic change makes me feel sick.
影帝 梅西 - Messi should win Oscar for Best Actor.
整理了一些（p.s，p.r）存货，都是干货 - Prepared some info I reserved before. They are all "information without beating around the bush"
讲的通俗易懂，都学完了，有想学习的吗？ - Speak in plain language. Have you learned all of it? What else do you want to learn? (or maybe "Anyone what to learn?")
再发挥一下价值，分享给有缘人。 - Make use of its surplus value again. Share it with whoever is lucky.
需要的留下邮箱，发给你 - Leave your email here, I will send it to you.
```